# MediaStream and MediaRecord with virtual device interface

Tags: io, mediarecorder, mediastream, blackhole

I am developing a simple application with the goal of familiarizing myself with the media stream and mediarecorder APIs. So in my application I made a simple functionality where it is to select the desired audio input and then proceed to record the audio using a button. After that, I made a button that allows you to stop recording and then proceed to save the recorded audio.

Now, I wanted to experiment via blackhole with the possibility of capturing audio generated from Youtube, for example. So to do that, I set up blackhole as my audio output (to be precise, I'm on macOS). So in my application I set blackhole as the audio input. This means that the audio generated by youtube represents the audio output of blackhole and, at the same time, represents the input of blackhole.

However, despite this configuration, the audio is not successfully retrieved. I wanted to do an experiment with OBS to verify the correctness of the configuration and it works.

So I was wondering if the API offered was somehow limiting? In the sense that it only works with physical audio interfaces?